# MYSQL query in PHP for a record that matched a date frame

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on an astrology horoscope website and I have a form that provides me with the person's birthday in my PHP code. 
In my MYSQL database, I have a column holding the sign's starting day date in a yyyy-mm-dd format.

here is my code so far.

```
$vdate = explode("-", $_POST['bDay']);
//input date

"SELECT `signs`.`bio`, `signs`.`startDate`, date_format(startDate,'%Y-%b-%d')
FROM `orion`.`signs`
WHERE (MONTH(startDate) = ."$vdate[1]". AND DAYOFMONTH(startDate) <= ."$vdate[2]".)
OR (MONTH(startDate) = ."($vdate[1]+1)". AND DAYOFMONTH(startDate) > ."$vdate[2]".);"

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
echo $row['bio'];
```

I get a error :

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$vdate' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\Apache24\htdocs\astro\getHoroscope.php on line 17
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are concatenating in a wrong way

```
"SELECT `signs`.`bio`, `signs`.`startDate`, date_format(startDate,'%Y-%b-%d')
FROM `orion`.`signs`
WHERE (MONTH(startDate) = ".$vdate[1]." AND DAYOFMONTH(startDate) <= ".$vdate[2].")
OR (MONTH(startDate) = ".($vdate[1]+1)." AND DAYOFMONTH(startDate) > ".$vdate[2].");"
```

The `.` is used to concatenate strings in PHP. It must be used after you close a string (Ex.: "aaa"."bbb" => aaabbb)

PS: Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection. Use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead.

Comment: Thanks so much! it's a school project, we are not covering that just yet.